# Set Header of TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `TabControl` which is bound to a List of `UserControls` (MyControls)

```
  <TabControl Background="{x:Null}" x:Name="MyView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyControls}" >
```

I want to bind the header of each tab item to a property(Title) in each `UserControl`. Which I did as below

```
<TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                 <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Title}"/>                   
                </Style>
</TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

However since I override the `ItemContainerStyle` I lost all the default style for the application. My tab header looks different from other tab headers in the application

Is there any way to just bind to the Title without changing any style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an `ItemTemplate`:

```
<TabControl Background="{x:Null}" x:Name="MyView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyControls}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

`MyControls` shouldn't return an `IEnumerable<UserControl>` though. It should return an `IEnumerable<YourObject>` where `YourObject` is a POCO class with a `Title` property along with any other properties. You should then use `DataTemplates` to define the appearance of a `YourObject`.

Comment: This is setting the tab item content? I just want to set the Header

Comment: It sets the Header. The `ContentTemplate` sets the content part.

Comment: That didn't work. In the item container style that is given in the question it is showing the header , albeit loosing all the style. "Title" is a property in the usercontrol which is the tab item content. However with the code given in this answer(with item template) it just didn't work.

Comment: Of course it works. Did you read my answer? MyControls shouldn't return any UIElements.

Comment: Just FYI, when I tried to bind to list of viewmodels with data template, the tab control started creating corresponding views in an infinite loop. I revert back to view first approach to make it work.

Comment: That's sounds very strange. You most certainly did something wrong then. Where did the views come from? If you create a new window/application and try my suggestion, you will see that it works.